# Run snakemake but with the .snakemake temporary files written elsewhere

Tags: bash, snakemake

Say I have a Snakemake workflow that has a `Snakefile` and various input files. I want to run this workflow exactly as it is, but with the `.snakemake` temporary files being written to a scratch filesystem which is better suited to writing.

I've tried the `--directory` flag, but this stops Snakemake from finding my input files, because they are located relative to the working directory. I want to use the current working directory for finding inputs, but only change where outputs are *written* to. Is this possible?

---

For example, if I use the [snakemake tutorial example](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/short.html):

```
.
├── data
│   ├── genome.fa
│   ├── genome.fa.amb
│   ├── genome.fa.ann
│   ├── genome.fa.bwt
│   ├── genome.fa.fai
│   ├── genome.fa.pac
│   ├── genome.fa.sa
│   └── samples
│       ├── A.fastq
│       ├── B.fastq
│       └── C.fastq
├── results
│   └── mapped
│       └── C.bam
└── workflow
    ├── envs
    │   ├── mapping.yaml
    │   └── stats.yaml
    └── Snakefile
```

I get `.snakemake` added in the current working directory. If I use `--directory ~/scratch/tmpsnake`, I get:

```
WorkflowError:
MissingInputException: Missing input files for rule map_reads:
    output: results/mapped/A.sorted.bam
    wildcards: sample=A.sorted
    affected files:
        data/genome.fa
        data/samples/A.sorted.fastq
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this is not possible directly. The indirect solution is to create a symbolic link from `.snakemake` to the scratch path. If `.snakemake` folder already exists, you will need to delete it (or move its contents to scratch path), and then create a symlink.

```bash
ln -s ~/scratch/tmpsnake .snakemake
```

The above command should be run once you cd into the folder where you want `.snakemake` to reside.