# set location of .snakemake directory

Tags: symlink, snakemake

Is there a way to define where snakemake creates the *.snakemake* folder.
I could change the whole working dic with `--directory`, however this also changes the storage location of every relative path.

I thought `--shadow-prefix` is what I was hoping for, but *.snakemake/scripts* for example is still created in the working dic.

The reasons is, that I am working on an shared CIFS/SMB drive (which I have no control over). In theory I have read/write access but for some actions snakemake performs in the .snakefile folder it refuses to give permission ([don't know why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77990826/cifs-smb-with-inconsistent-read-write-permissions)). So my hope is that i could place *.snakemake* on a small local drive, but the data of the workflow is still written to the CIFS/SMB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible, at least with the latest version available today. The [workaround for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77624454/10693596) is to create a symlink to the path that works best for you:

```bash
ln -s MY_PATH .snakemake
```

where `MY_PATH`  is the location you would like to use to store the `.snakemake`-related files.